# Member initialization list vs assignment/copy constructor (in boost deadline_timer)

Tags: c++, boost, member-initialization

I have the following class declaration:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t;
};
```

The following constructor for class `A` works fine:

```
A::A() : t(io) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But when I write this:

```
A::A() {
    t(io);
    // do stuff
}
```

I get the following error:

> error: no match for call to ‘(boost::asio::deadline_timer {aka
>   boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer})
>   (boost::asio::io_service&)

Perhaps because the copy constructor for `boost::asio::deadline_timer` is not defined. But what is happening in case of member initialization list? Does it not use the copy constructor?

My question perhaps can be made more general in regard to what is the mechanism used in member initialization lists vs when we use assignment/copy constructor inside the class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with copy constructor, and you didn't call it at all. The point is the two `t(io)`s are not the same thing.

`t(io)` in member initialization list means construct `t` by the constructor taking `io` as its argument. (I suppose `boost::asio::deadline_timer` has a constructor taking `boost::asio::io_service` as parameter.)

`t(io)` in the body of constructor is a statement, means calling `t` as a functor, passing `io` as its argument. It fails because `boost::asio::deadline_timer` doesn't support such functor behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer to my question. Quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the
>   constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases,
>   virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member
>   initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of
>   these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be
>   default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified
>   types, member initializers must be specified.

So in my case, the copy constructor for boost::asio::deadline_timer is not defined. Therefore I need to construct it inside the initializer list.